# insert number +1 for every row inserted

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php script:

```
for ($i = 0, $count = count($ingredientQTY); $i < $count; $i++) {
            $yo = 1;
            $rows[] = array(
                'ingredientamount'         => $ingredientQTY[$i],
                'ingredientType' =>  $measurements[$i],
                'ingredientname'        => $ingredientNAME[$i],
                'recipe_id' => $recipe_id
            );
            $sql = "INSERT `ingredients` (`ingredientamount`,`ingredientType`,`ingredientname`, `recipe_id`) VALUES ";
            $coma = '';
            foreach ($rows as $oneRow) {
                $sql .= $coma."('".implode("','",$oneRow)."')";
                $coma = ', ';
            }
            $this->db->query($sql);
      }

      break;
}
```

which inserts a row (containing ingredientamount, ingredientType, and ingrientname) into the table ingredients. I also have an **order** column which should start at 1, and for every row inserted, add 1 to **order**. How can I do this with my current code? I thought maybe I'd have to have a hidden field that I passed in, but is there a way to do this with PHP?

Thanks for all help, and if the way I described this is in any way confusing, please just ask!

Comment: @Arjan, I was thinking of doing it auto increment, but I read a SO answer that said you shouldn't use auto increment if your going to change the values in the column all the time (I let the user change the order of each row)?? Is that correct?

Comment: You can have a seperate column for ordering, but AI is the best way to ensure unique IDs on a per-row basis

Comment: @Simon, Thanks, I'm already using a id column that is primary and autoincremented. Should I use autoincrement on the order column as well?

Comment: You can have only one auto-increment column per table, and the id column is the best one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a counter `$i` for your loop, just insert `$i + 1` as the value for the field.

Comment: well that was easier than expected :) Thanks!